# How to load and draw png image in Haxe (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, canvas, haxe

Earlier I used something like this (html5+javascript):

```
var img;
  window.onload = function(){  
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");  
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");  
  img = new Image();  
  img.onload = function() {  
  context.drawImage(img,0,0);  
  };  
  img.src = "maze.png";
```

Now I learn Haxe (platform-javascript) and can't write this code in accordance with js-libraries. I've found examples only for vector drawing.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "can't write this code in accordance with js-libraries"?

Comment: js.html.CanvasRenderingContext2D, js.html.Image, js.html.ImageData,
js.Browser. We have access to javascript code only through these libraries.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possible to port that code to javascript; to find javascript classes in the Haxe API, just search them on [api.haxe.org](http://api.haxe.org). In this case, the Image class is `js.html.Image`. Here is a basic example of image drawing: [view example on try.haxe](https://try.haxe.org/#f1Cbf)

```
var canvas = js.Browser.document.createCanvasElement();
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;
js.Browser.document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var ctx = canvas.getContext2d();
var img = new js.html.Image();  
img.onload = function() {  
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);  
};  
img.src = "http://dreamicus.com/data/maze/maze-02.jpg";
```

Alternative libraries exist that make this easier and more cross platform. You are not using the full haxe ecosystem to it's full if you are just writing code to get compiled to javascript - libraries such as kha and phaser will let you draw an image using a standard API that will let you target any platform.

Answer (score 2):

You can port the exact code to Haxe:
https://try.haxe.org/#a7287

```
import js.Browser.*;
import js.html.*;

class Test {
    static function main() {
        var img;
        window.onload = function() {  
            var canvas:CanvasElement = cast document.getElementById("myCanvas");  
            var context = canvas.getContext2d();  
            img = document.createImageElement();  
            img.onload = function() {  
                context.drawImage(img,0,0);  
            };
            img.src = "maze.png";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a more suitable alternative to my answer's code, though just ensure that the compiled javascript is added to a html page with a canvas element with the id `myCanvas`. Mine works in try.haxe because the JS makes the canvas element, though I wouldn't recommend that in production.

Comment: There are good reasons to use pre-existed canvas element and OP knows them by himself. And how I understand his question is that he wants to know how to write his code in Haxe.